# trying to reverse my android animation even number of times

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I have this animation code

```
  private void shakeTooltip() {

    if (MapView.gpuSupported() != MapView.GPU_SUPPORTED) return;

    final TranslateAnimation breathUpTranslateAnimation =
        new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0F, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -0.05F);
    breathUpTranslateAnimation.setDuration(TOOLTIP_ANIM_DURATION * 3);
    breathUpTranslateAnimation.setRepeatCount(2);
    breathUpTranslateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    breathUpTranslateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    // breathUpTranslateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    toolTipLayout.startAnimation(breathUpTranslateAnimation);
  }
```

I want my view to move up and down 2 times and end its animation at down position.

however, now it moves up, down, up and then moves to down position without translate animation

as if it does restart. It appears in down position and not moves there.

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your repeat count to 3 instead. The jump back that you are seeing is because your animation's setFillAfter is default to false, if you manually set it to true it will stay in place at the end of the animation. Hence why you need to up the repeat count to 3.

Comment: but how come? one- going up. 2nd- going down. 3rd- going up again?

Comment: Repeat count doesn't count the first time the animation happens, it counts the number of times after that to repeat it. So when you set repeat count to 3: 0-going up (not a repeat), 1- going down (repeat), 2- going up (repeat), 3- going down (repeat).